# Difference in function.promise.then() and function.then()

Tags: javascript, promise, pdf.js

What is difference between `function.promise.then()` and `function.then()`

I am working on a small PDF viewer using PDF.js

`pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(pdfDoc1=>{})` works fine but if I convert it to

`pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).then(pdfDoc1=>{})` it doesn't return anything.

Can someone explain the difference in the two?

Comment: Well, have you read the documentation of `getDocument()`? What does it return?

Comment: The `.getDocument()` API returns an object, and on that object there is a property called "promise".

Answer (score 0):

> `pdfjsLib.getDocument('helloworld.pdf')`
>
> Remember though that PDF.js uses promises, and the above will return a
> `PDFDocumentLoadingTask` instance that has a `promise` property which is
> resolved with the document object.

Source: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/